# Inserting a valid html link into a string for an email

Tags: c#

I'm building a string that will be sent over email. In the string I'd like to include a link, like so:

```
String mailstring = "Blah blah blah blah. Click here for more information."
```

and I'd like the "here" to be a link in the email, such as putting it http://madeuplink.com. I know I can put the address instead of the 'here' but I'd like to have the link be the word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add HTML markup. Assuming the client has HTML emails enabled, it should become a link. If you're using [MailDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx) to create the email, then ensure that the [IsBodyHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.isbodyhtml.aspx) property is set to true.

```
String mailstring = "Blah blah blah blah. Click <a href=\"http://www.example.com\">here</a> for more information."
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that html markup would work for this, thanks.

Comment: Hey is there some kind of Namespace I need include or a reference?  This isn't working for me...  :(

`m_sMessage = "To learn more about FabPro1, Visit <a href=\"http://www.fabpro1.com\">our website</a>";`

Comment: @UchihaItachi You'll need to add `System.Web`

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

```
 string input = String.Format("Blah blah blah blah. Click {0} for more information.", 
                    "<a href=\"http://www.example.com\">here</a>");
```

OR

```
 string input = "Blah blah blah blah. Click <a href=\"http://www.example.com\">here</a> for more information.",
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one thing to add to @keyboardP's comment even though it is a bit out of context, if you are using MailMessage object to be sent as a message using SmtpClient, you need to set the `MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true`.

`public void SendEmail(string to, string subject, string body)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("someone@example.com", to);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        ...
        }`

The HTML markup will take the desired form in the email only when this property is set, otherwise it will show the markup as text and not a hyperlink.